# String split with Regex returns no value

Tags: java, regex, split

I am new to **Regex** and very confused why there get no groups returned by the `split`method in the following operation:

```
String toSplit ="FN:Your Name";
String splitted [] = toSplit.split("(FN:)([A-Za-z]*) ([A-Za-z]*)");
System.out.println("Length: "+splitted.length);
```

**Output:**
`Length: 0`

**Question:** What is the reason and how can I get `Your` and `Name` returned in the array?

Comment: The regex matches the whole string, thus after splitting, nothing is left. `.split()` docs: The string "boo:and:foo", for example, yields the following results with these expressions: 



Regex

Result

`:  { "boo", "and", "foo" }}`
`o  { "b", "", ":and:f" }}`

Comment: You probably want to use a [Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html), not to split

Comment: If you want to use split to get your matches, try using a character class:  `System.out.println(Arrays.toString("FN:Your Name".split("[: ]")));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to split but to use a [Matcher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html):

```java
String toSplit ="FN:Your Name";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:FN:)([A-Za-z]*) ([A-Za-z]*)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(toSplit);
if (matcher.find()) {
    String[] splitted = new String[]{
        matcher.group(1),
        matcher.group(2)
    };
    System.out.println("splitted: " + Arrays.toString(splitted));
}
```

Result:

```
splitted: [Your, Name]
```

Small note: I've made the first group non capturing with `?:` because you don't need to get it in the result.

Comment: oh yeah, code fences work [as advertised](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288374/support-commonmark-fenced-code-blocks/378734#378734)

Comment: @Alan split is used to b break a string by a separator (which might be complex or not). For example you might want it to use it to get an initially unknown number of words in a sentence.